# How do you check if the data is null in http.get in angularjs AND do something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-http

My code:

```
<script>  
 function  customersController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("https://tic.com/testingservice/HttpService.svc/operator/Var1/Var2")
        .success(function (response) { $scope.names = response; });
    }
 </script>

<table class="plansbox" cellspacing="0" rules="all" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FULLTALKTIME" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tbody><tr class="rechargeplansheader">
            <th scope="col">AMOUNT</th><th scope="col">TALKTIME</th><th scope="col">VALIDITY</th><th scope="col">DESCRIPTION</th>
        </tr><tr class="GridRow" ng-repeat="x in names | filter: { plantype: 'TopUp' }" onclick="label1('220');" style="font-family:Verdana;cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">
            <td style="width:10%;">

                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FULLTALKTIME_ctl02_lblAmount" style="font-weight:bold;">{{ x.Amount }}</span>
                </td><td style="width:10%;">
                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FULLTALKTIME_ctl02_lbltalktime" style="font-weight:bold;">{{x.Talktime }}</span>
                </td><td style="width:10%;">
                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FULLTALKTIME_ctl02_lblvalidity" style="font-weight:bold;">{{ x.Validity }}</span>
                </td><td style="width:70%;">
                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FULLTALKTIME_ctl02_lbldescription">{{ x.Description}}</span>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

As you can see I am able to get the data, check if the returned data is null, but do to show another div in the null case.

Please help me I am new to angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `ng-if="!names"`, also for more better you maintain a flag which will give you information about data fetching ajax done or not. & that could be very useful while **No data found** div

**Controller**

```
var customersController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.dataLoaded = false; //data loading done or not
    $http.get("https://tic.com/testingservice/HttpService.svc/operator/Var1/Var2")
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.dataLoaded = true;
      $scope.names = response;
    });
}

app.controller('customersController', ['$scope', '$http', customersController]);
```

**Markup**

```
  <table class="plansbox" cellspacing="0" rules="all" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FULLTALKTIME" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
      <tr class="rechargeplansheader">
        <th scope="col">AMOUNT</th>
        <th scope="col">TALKTIME</th>
        <th scope="col">VALIDITY</th>
        <th scope="col">DESCRIPTION</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-if="dataLoaded && (!names || names.length === 0)" colspan="4">
        <td>No data found</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data-loading" ng-if="!dataLoaded" colspan="4">
        <td>Data is loading</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="dataLoaded" class="GridRow" ng-repeat="x in names | filter: { plantype: 'TopUp' }" onclick="label1('220');" style="font-family:Verdana;cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">
        <td style="width:10%;">
          <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FULLTALKTIME_ctl02_lblAmount" style="font-weight:bold;">{{ x.Amount }}</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:10%;">
          <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FULLTALKTIME_ctl02_lbltalktime" style="font-weight:bold;">{{x.Talktime }}</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:10%;">
          <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FULLTALKTIME_ctl02_lblvalidity" style="font-weight:bold;">{{ x.Validity }}</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width:70%;">
          <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FULLTALKTIME_ctl02_lbldescription">{{ x.Description}}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pSfu9je1rAFjijjyAhVV?p=preview)

**Update**

Additionally you could do add one more flag which would give you information about ajax in addition with `names` you could use `dataLoaded` flag. While ajax is in progress set `dataLoaded` value to false, after completion of ajax set `dataLoaded` to true.

You could show or hide any `div` on your html by using `ng-show`, `ng-hide` or `ng-if` directive. Only you need to specify expression value in it, depends on expression value true/false it will show/hide that `div` element.

As in above example I used `ng-if="dataLoaded && (!names || names.length === 0)"` which evaluated the expression and will show that `div` only when ajax is completed & names array does have value or its length is Zero(0)

Comment: I am using it if($scope.dataLoaded = true) { alert("data loaded");} everytime it is going in to it either data is null or not.

Comment: @user3630591 did you try what I gave in answer

Comment: i want to show this div on dataload successful. If the data is null i should show another div

Comment: <tr class="no-data-found" ng-if="dataLoaded && !names" colspan="4">
            No data found
        </tr> it is visible although the dataloaded perfectly

Comment: if service is returning data as null then do `<tr class="no-data-found" ng-if="dataLoaded && names == null" colspan="4"> No data found </tr>`

Comment: the data response will be   [ ] if no data is returned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75594/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-user3630591).

Comment: @user3630591 did you checked it?

Comment: yeah i have checked the plunkr. How to do something like showing another div if it is true or false can you elaborate. I can find the data is null or not in that html. Is there any way to do it in the script so that i could do something if it is false